# Does the plane go through the origin?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

To show that there are three real numbers $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, not all zero, such that $$\alpha \overrightarrow{a}+\beta\overrightarrow{b}+\gamma\overrightarrow{c}=\overrightarrow{0}$$ we do the following:

We suppose that there are $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ so that $\alpha \overrightarrow{a}+\beta\overrightarrow{b}+\gamma\overrightarrow{c}=\overrightarrow{0}$ and $\alpha \neq 0$, then $\overrightarrow{a}=(-\frac{\beta}{\alpha})\overrightarrow{b}+(-\frac{\gamma}{\alpha})\overrightarrow{c}$. So $\alpha$ is at the plane that is defined by $\beta$, $\gamma$. 
(similar when $\beta \neq 0, \gamma \neq 0$).

My question is the following:

Do we know that the plane goes through the origin??

Comment: Yes, since $\vec{0}=0\vec{b}+0\vec{c}$.

Comment: can we just  set the vectors equal to zero?? @hjhjhj57

Comment: What do you mean? Whenever you multiply a vector by a scalar you do it componentwise. So $0\vec{b}=\vec{0}$ for every vector $\vec{b}$. (I've edited my previous comment.)

Comment: I see... Thank you!! :-) @hjhjhj57